# Fail to call php accessing another php under same domain

Tags: php

I need to call the (http://example.com/data/api/index.php) index.php from (http://example.com/data/test.php) test.php. Note that they are under the same domain.

Here show the code in test.php:

```
$url_head = "http://example.com/data/api/index.php";  
$url = $url_head."?controller=A&action=B";

$data = array("smth" => $something);
$response=postData($data,$url);       // request here!
$decode = json_decode($response);


function postData($data,$url){
    $postdata = http_build_query(
        $data
    );
    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);

    $result = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
    return $result;
}
```

Once I run test.php, the request wait for 15 seconds and giving a result showing unable to get anything.

However, If I run the index.php directly, it shows response quickly and releasing correct output.

Can someone help to solve the problem? With some purpose, I really need to have a caller before going into index.php.

Comment: You'll need to show your `postData()` function at least. See the webservers log file for more concrete infos, if the request submitted at all (else server config or possibly even local firewall issue.)

Comment: OK, I've appended postData()

Comment: Just like this ?  `$url = $url_head."?controller=A&action=B";`

Comment: I've solved this problem, by switching some server config.